# Attaching image to email through Parse's Sendgrid module using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, email, parse-platform, sendgrid, parse-cloud-code

I was wondering if anyone knew how to send an email with an image attached to it from Parse's Sendgrid module (by this, I mean Facebook's Parse BaaS, not SendGrid's Parse API). So far, I can send out emails, but not with an image attached to it. I tried two different things. One is sending the email as Base64, but I read that is not supported by A LOT of email providers, therefore I was discouraged in using this method since compatibility is kind of an issue here (not critical though). My second approach was to try to mimic sendgrid's process of using a `cid`, but maybe I was doing something wrong and it did not work

```
var sendGridInstance = require('sendgrid');
    sendGridInstance.initialize(sendGridUser, sendGridKey);
    sendGridInstance.sendEmail({
         to:endCustomerEmail,
         from: 'test@test.com',
         subject: 'Test subject',
         html: 'My HTML goes here..',
         replyto: 'donotreply@test.com'
```

The code above works whenever it is called in CloudCode, and indeed sends an email. But the cid thing does not work.

Has anyone successfully sent an email w/image using the sendgrid module with Parse? If so, could you please tell me what am I missing?

All help is much appreaciated!

Thank you!

Cheers!

Comment: Could you include more of the code you're using to send the image in your tests - it looks like some of your code was cut off and it'll be easier to help if we can see the whole thing.

Comment: I will! Give me a minute!

Answer (score 0):

This module doesn't support binary files - it calls SendGrid API with **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** request and you can't urlencode contents of binary file. 
Take a look at https://github.com/m1gu3l/parse-sendgrid-mailer instead - it calls API with **multipart/form-data** request which is [better suited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data) for this case.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10515357)

Comment: Well, it's a repo with module that supports binary files, I don't know what you expectected me to include.